# How to make a floating div which show another div when we click it

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-float

I am trying to create a div (**show**) at top-right of the window which look like button. If the user click it then another div (**form**) should open up along with div (**show**) sliding down. So i used jquery slideToggle to Take Care of it. Now, if I click the div (**show**) it slideToggle div (**form**) but this two divs moves the third div (**ano**) down. That is this two affect other divs. I want this two div open up like a slider without affecting other I guess it should come at the top index. Here is the code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      .ano {
         background-image:url('pic1.jpg');
         position:
       }
      .show {
         display: block;
         margin-top: -10px;
         background-image:url('button.png');
         margin-left: 85%;
         background-repeat:no-repeat; 
       }
      .form {
         display: block;
         margin-top: -10px;
         background-image:url('slider.png');
         background-repeat:no-repeat;
         margin-left: 85%;
       }
      body {
         background-image:url('bg.jpg');
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

   <div class="form">
     Here are some content
   </div>
   <div class="show">
     click me
   </div>
   <div class="ano">
     different div
   </div>

<script>
   $(".show").click(function() {
     $(".form").slideToggle();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: It works fine as expected right? DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/BtEUF/

Comment: yes.But different div that is div(**ano**) is moving:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could do it. You could wrap the form and show in another div, that is fixed in the top right corner:

```
.sitInCorner {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width:15%;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BtEUF/1/)

This will always make the `.show` and `.form` be in the top right corner, no matter what, and it will not effect any other elements on the page.

Hope this does what you want! ^_^

**Edit:**

If you want the `.form` tag to start out hidden, add this to the CSS:

```
display:none;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BtEUF/5/)

Comment: Why the **form** div displaying when i load the page? It should display after i click **show** right?

Comment: Look at the updated jsfiddle ... it needs to be set to `display:hidden` to start with. Now you can get fancy and also toggle an up or down arrow in the show div and stuff like that =) Good luck with the page!

Comment: Of course, if you'd want the **form div** to be underneath the **click me div**, the only thing you should do is place that **div** underneath the **click me div** in your HTML.

Comment: Ya fine.Thank you Martin Turjak.can i ask one more question

Comment: I am new to css & jquery that's why am asking more questions.Now i want that **show** div to place on right sidebar.If i click it then **form** div should come from right to left.is this possible?

Comment: yes! you can use for example jQuerie's [**.animate()**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), with it you can animate a lot of different properties. And just as a hint: if you position `.form` inside the `.show`, and add to them `position:absolute;` and `position:relative;` respectively, you can position the `.form` anywhere relative to the `.show` div =)

Comment: can you please give a fiddle for this?

Comment: [here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/BtEUF/16/). [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) has avery good documentation, and there is tons of tutorials online to get a better grasp of CSS and javascript. Hope I answered your question now and gave you at least an idea of where to start. Best of luck! ^_^

Comment: So this is called wrapping a div right? OK Thank you for your consideration to resolve my doubts.

Comment: Well yes, the word **wrapping** will often refer to putting a container around another element, but it can have some other meanings too, like [word-wrapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fword-wrap) inline things in their parent container or [wrapping text around floated things](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/float.php). And you are welcome, I am glad to help ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Try It:

```
.ano
{
background-image:url('pic1.jpg');
position:absolute;
top:20px;
}
```

Hope it will Help you..!!